# Is usage of machen correct here?

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure, standard-german

My sentence:

> There are some games and also videos available in order to make learning easier.
> Es gibt einige Spiele und auch Videos um einfach lernen zu machen.

Translator:

> Es gibt einige Spiele und Videos, die das Lernen erleichtern.

Can we use *"lernen"* and *"machen"* in same sentence with *"um ... zu"* format?

Here, in German lessons is the same word written in the topic, then have I written the below sentence correct?
Context is different medium of teaching German.

> ..., dass es andere Medien auch um Deutschunterricht zu machen gibt.

Not sure whether the question should have separated the word *"Deutsch"* and *"Unterricht".*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between the English version and your translation: "to make sth. easier" means it becomes less difficult than before, while "einfach" means it becomes actually easy. (The former meaning is also reflected in "erleichtern".) Thus, you'd have to use the comparative "einfacher" in German, as well.

With that in mind, you got it almost right:

> Es gibt einige Spiele und auch Videos um das Lernen einfacher zu machen.

Note that "einfacher" is directly connected to "zu machen" because it modifies that word. And then, you'd transform the verb "lernen" into a noun.